# django celery get() for getting the result form task

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I have an API call to the server where I am doing some processing using celery. The output from the celery is passed back to client.

I used

```
som = task_async_get_cached_session.delay('session_123')
print 'before'
result = som.get(timeout=1)
print 'after'
```

I looked at the `celery -l INFO` and the task get succeeded in 
`succeeded in 0.024465521s: {data: {session_123: something}}`

But my client was not get response back and and I put timeout and now I am getting `The operation timed out. (<class 'celery.exceptions.TimeoutError'>)`

When I looked at the logs trace, only `before` is printed. My question how to use celery without `get()` when you want the result generated from the celery task to the client?

I know that `get()` will convert my API call to synchronous, but what alternate I have ? What is the real use of celery ? Is there any other way to change my API to behave Asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

Use [celery.result](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html) to design a function to check task state and get result.

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult

def get_result(my_work):
    work = AsyncResult(my_work.id)
    if work.ready():                     # check task state: true/false
        try:
            result = work.get(timeout=1) 
            return result
        except:
            pass

    return "Please waiting result."
```

Comment: In this case lets say I pass {"status":"Please waiting result.", "taskId":"123"}. Then client use this taskId in another API /status/<taskId> to get the result ? .. Is this the only way to make server Async ?

Comment: Yes, Use `taskId` to get result. You could use session or database to store `taskId` by every user. Then user doesn't need to remember this id by himself.

Comment: Because maybe the message broker work on remote server. :)